# Не закрывается меню при переходе по ссылке Bootstrap3

Tags: bootstrap

Всем привет. У меня меню в мобильной версии сайта на Bootstrap не закрывается автоматически, когда я уже перешел по ссылке.Обшарил кучу форумов, но у меня ни 1 код не сработал :( Подскажите пожалуйста что попробовать. Заранее спасибо за решение!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button data-target="#navbar-collapse-02" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Управление навигацией</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar-collapse-02" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                  
            <li><a href="index.html#home_wrapper">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#conception">Наша концепция</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#etapi">Этапы проверки авто</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#pricing">Цены</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#ulovki">Уловки продавцов</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#contact">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: проверьте js bootstrap подключен?

Comment: подключен bootstrap.min.js . это то что нужно, или еще что-то нужно?